# Read only first column from txt file

Tags: python

I have simple txt file with maybe 6 columns and 10000 rows. How can i read only first column and save it in some array?

Every solution that i tried didn't work.

I manage it with octave very simply,

```
data = load("sample.txt") 
first_column = data(:,1)
```

EDIT: I forgot to metion, I have to rows of strings that i need to skip. 
My file starts like this:

## ib*ns    Average  E /mK    Average Ek /mK    Average Ep /mK   walkers

## --------  ------------ ---  ------------ ---  ------------ ---  --------

```
  2000   -89.4010789        736.581586       -825.982664          4988
  4000   -86.8499373        707.358765       -794.208703          4952
  6000   -87.3911178        680.584591       -767.975709          4968
```

Comment: Pandas library would be the closest alternative to Octave/Matlab

Comment: How are the columns delimited?

Comment: Not Python but quite quick: `cut -d, -f1 < so.txt`

Comment: I forgot to mention, i have got first two rows with some text and i will have to skip it. And then, just integers in columns and rows delimited with tab

Answer (score 4):

the following code works if the separator between columns is a tab. Otherwise adjust to whatever the separator is.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', header=None, usecols=[1], sep='\t')
```

note that despite read_csv claiming it reads csv's, it can read any text file with a consistent separator

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `CSV` file, then I'd recommend using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

In general though the solution is something like:

```
DELIMITER = ' '
data = []
with open('test.txt') as fr:
  for line in fr:
    first_col = line.split('{}'.format(DELIMITER))[0]
    data.append(first_col)
```

You can replace `DELIMITER` with whatever you want (spaces, tabs, etc.)

Or, as @cricket_007 says, use the Python csv module. Something like:

```
lines = csv.reader(open('test.txt', 'rb'), delimiter=DELIMITER)
```

Comment: Importing the csv module would be safer, depending on the delimiter and field types

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `csv` module provides this functionality:

```
import csv
with open('data.dat', 'r') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
     first_column = [ row[0] for row in reader ]
```

This code extracts the first column into a list as requested.